# Объединить /boot и /boot/efi в один /boot раздел?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, boot, uefi

В сети много где написано, что в UEFI биосе должна быть загрузочная запись в разделе `/boot/efi` в fat32 и определенный объем, допустим 500Мб. Часто он заполнен на 1% (или около того) и *пропадает* в каком то смысле место. Мой раздел `/boot` почти заполнен, а его общий размер составляет 1G между тем я задался вопросом, как можно (и можно ли вообще) объединить эти два раздела?
Вижу следующие действия загрузившись из SystemRescue:
скопировать всё из разделов `/boot` и `/boot/efi` в одну папку например `/home/boot`
удалить оба раздела, создать один и перенести всё содержимое `/home/boot` вместе с `/home/boot/efi` используя тем самым один раздел для загрузки и grub. Но прежде чем делать, хотелось бы понять можно ли так делать. В сети я находил подобные вопросы но прямых ответов не нашел.

Comment: Если их объединить, тогда не будет uefi загрузки, но может оно вам и не нужно. Вместо объединения, я бы посоветовал просто уменьшить объём.

Comment: Скорее всего нельзя. Там не просто так другой раздел. Если много места занимает, попробуйте это изменить. Но раздел убирать не очень разумно.

Comment: `(и можно ли вообще) объединить эти два раздела?` - сделать то можно, но могут всплыть разные нюансы при переносе и чтобы всё учесть нужно потыкать в той же виртуалке. У меня к примеру изначально(когда устанавливал систему арч) efi завязан через раздел `/boot` - см. [первый вариант: mount ESP to /boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition#Typical_mount_points) а также вместо загрузчика `grub` используется встроенный(идёт с systemd) `systemd-boot` и всё отлично работает.

Comment: чем вы его заполнили на один гигабайт то?)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFISTUB  попробуй. но приготовь лайфдиск заранее